# cannot download the app on ios version 9.2

Tags: ios

i launch my app but when i start it download on device of ios 9.2 an error message shown "The app required ios version 9.3" what is the reason. i setup deployment target to 9.3 in xcode and my test device where also 9.3

Comment: So, you set your deployment target to 9.3 and you are asking why you can't install on a device with 9.2 when the message clearly says "This app requires iOS 9.3"?

Comment: yup i got that but how could i set the minimum and max iOS versions like in between 8.0 - 9.3 that could run the app

Comment: You only set the minimum.  You can't set a maximum.  If you set your deployment target to 8.0 then your app can be installed on a device with 8.0  or higher; up to 9.3.  If Apple releases 9.4 then your app will be installable on a device with 9.4

Comment: if i set the target to 8.0 then can it be installable on iPad `? since i pad have versions of 4.2 or something my app is universal

Comment: If you select 8.0 then your app can be installed on an iPad if it is running iOS 8.0 or later.  It can't be installed on an iPad running iOS 4.2

Comment: when i set the target to 8.0 i gets the error "in app purchase is not available for the user enrolled" something like that how could i resolve that

Comment: The availability of in-app purchasing is nothing to do with the iOS target.  It is more likely that the user or device does not have in app purchasing permission. In app purchasing is not available on the simulator, for example.  You need to check where your app is producing that error message and see why.

Comment: i m updating my Xcode after that i will try to figure out the error post me an answer so that i can accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1.-> setup deployment target to 9.2 or below in xcode
option 2-> update your device with 9.3 version

Comment: if i set deployment target to 8.0 will iOS 9.3 be able to run the app, what does actually the deployment target meant

Comment: yes if you set deployment target to 8.0 , you can run any iOS  greater than 8.0. Like you will able to run 8.1, 8.2, 9.1,9.2,.... , But you cant run iOS lower than 8.0. Like You will not able to run 7.3,7.2 ,6.2 .... so on

Comment: i m getting the setting for deployment target two times, one under the app.target , and one in app.project where to set

Comment: you can accept my answer  , and upvote me if you satisfy with my answer sir.

Answer (score 1):

If the deployment target of your app is 9.3, you cannot install this app to earlier versions. Change deployment target to 9.0 or earlier to support devices with earlier versions of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

The deployment target setting specifies the lowest operating system version that your app can run on.
then if you set 9.3, you app cannot run in ios version lower than 9.3

Comment: how  could i set the deployment target for iPad

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to run on IOS 9.2, you have to set the deployment target to 9.2. And it will work.

As Apple says:

> The deployment target setting specifies the lowest operating system version that your app can run on. For example, the lowest available setting for iPad apps is iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

Change your project deployment target to 9.0 or other but you are set deployment target version after and equal os version to test in device before version doesn't test.